# Display plot pgfplots multicolumns

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following data & I'm trying to display a plot similar to the screenshot

```
items,section_1,section_2,section_3,section_4
10,82,42,38,22
20,38,24,20,63
30,44,49,39,40
40,58,48,47,47
50,58,45,59,41
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable MWE including `\documentclass` and the appropriate `packages` that sets up the problem, and shows what you have tried. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 9):

No MWE no explanation :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
items,section_1,section_2,section_3,section_4
10,82,42,38,22
20,38,24,20,63
30,44,49,39,40
40,58,48,47,47
50,58,45,59,41
}\mytable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,4}{
\addplot table[x=items,y=section_#1]{\mytable};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No explanation, no up-vote :) (Of course, I'm kidding, I already up-voted).