# Multiple data columns in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose we got a .txt data file myplot.txt from MATLAB, and it contains in total 51 columns. I want to plot these data in `pgfplots` in the following way. The first column of myplot.txt is always for the x-axis, while each of the columns 2 to 51 is for the y-axis, starting from the plot (column 1, column 2) until the plot (column 1, column 51). That is, I want to plot 50 figures in the same plot. I am trying to use the following code. However, it does not work correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,xmin=0,xmax=1,
xtick={0,1},
ymin=0,ymax=1,
width=7cm]
\addplot[color=black,mark=none,x index=0,y index=1] table {myplot.txt};
\addplot[color=black,mark=none,x index=0,y index=2] table {myplot.txt};
\addplot[color=black,mark=none,x index=0,y index=3] table {myplot.txt};
....
\addplot[color=black,mark=none,x index=0,y index=50] table {myplot.txt};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there anyone know how to do this? Thanks very much.

Comment: You say it does not work correctly, but you are not telling what goes wrong. Are there any errors? We have no data to test. Can you at least provide a small example, of how a file looks like? It is important for pgfplots to know how the columns are separated.

Comment: Would this help http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170212/34618.

Comment: Matlab might export the data with tab separators, then you need `col sep=tab` at each table option. Same goes for comma separated values.